# How to estimate joint probability or conditional probability using marginal ones?

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution, generative-models

I have 2 datasets:

- The 1st one gives us the probability that $m$ events occur on $n$ observations ($m$ columns for $n$ rows)
- The 2nd one tells us if the event occurred (1 if occurred, 0 else ; always $m$ columns for $n$ rows)

My goal is to predict all the combinations of joint events for future observations of $m$ probabilities.

First, I wanted to train a multioutput classification model using a discriminative model:
$$P(X_k \cap X_j|X) = f(X)$$
But the number of combinations tending towards infinity if we wish to predict more than 2 joint events, this solution does not seem possible.

Then, to keep the dimension of my target $y$, I thought of using the formula of conditional probabilities:
$$P(X_k \cap X_j) = P(X_k|X_j) \times P(X_j)$$

Because I have $P(X_j)$, I just have to predict $P(X_k|X_j)$, and the dimension of the target $y$ stays constant ($m$).

First, I tried to use discriminative model, changing the probability of the conditional event to 1 but the results are not good enough.

I also tried to use generative model, like Bayesian networks, but in the same way, the results are not good enough.

Do you have a trick or a smart idea to address this issue please ?

FYI: I also thought about the use of copulas, but they seem to me more useful to propose probability distributions than for a predictions.

Comment: Unfortunately, knowing the marginal probabilities is not enough to determine the joint density, unless you assume independence of course.

Comment: I don't want the density, but I would like to predict an estimation for a particular observation.

Comment: Something like the Gaussian Naive Bayes described partway down this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier (the GNB is not a classifier, though)?

Comment: Already used, but the results are not good enough.